# hide/show the panel using <p:command> and <p:outputpanel>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am a new to jsf and primefaces.I want to implement that while clicking on button two link should be enable while clicking on the same button again that two link become disabled. I have created a example using `<h:commandButton>` and java bean to hide show but no idea with the `<p:commandButton>` and `<p:outputPanel>`.

I have achieved that while click on the link the 2 link will be enable.

Problem is but again clicking on that it has to be disable which was not working

Comment: use  `render` attribute

Comment: Do you want them disabled or removed completely?

Comment: i want them to work on click event to show and hide like on click it show and on second click it become hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you:

```
<h:form id="mainform">
    <p:commandButton value="#{testBean.enabled ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}" action="#{testBean.toggle()}" update="links, @this"/>
    <p:outputPanel id="links">
        <p:link value="link1" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" rendered="#{testBean.enabled}"/>
        <p:spacer width="10"/>
        <p:link value="link2" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" rendered="#{testBean.enabled}"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
private Boolean enabled = false; // + getter/setter
public void toggle() {
    enabled = !enabled;
}
```

Comment: hi,thanks for ur answer but somehow i m not able to run the code the output is not coming as per the criteria. I m facing issue with <p:command> in .xhtml file . I m pasting my file

Comment: @ArpitThakkar You can have 1 actionListener and 1 action, though they are meant for different stuff - read up on it. And you can nest additional f:actionListener's inside, so you can call all the methods you want. You could also just have an action, and from that method call 100 other methods. Remember to accept answers to your questions :-)

Comment: @ArpitThakkar If it works for you would you accept the answer please? Is it that difficult to do?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add as answer.It works perfectly for me